# How to show date as per server date format after publishing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my web application I have to show date as per server date format.
If server machine has date format `07-Feb-2017`. When I run application from Visual studio it shows correct format `07-Feb-2017`.

But if i published it on Internet information system & run from there I got format like `2/7/2017`

How to Solve it?

Comment: How about some code showing how you're retrieving and outputting the date.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the date format in IIS and make it in sync with that of server

```
In IIS 7
Select your website
Open .NET Globalizaion
Select required Culture and UI Culture.
Reset IIS
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the date itself, format it as a string.... ala

```
Public Function Server_Date() as string
    Return Today.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
End Function
```